# (Python) Stop thread with raw input?

Tags: python, multithreading

**EDIT 9/15/16:** In my original code (still posted below) I tried to use `.join()` with a function, which is a silly mistake because it can only be used with a thread object. I am trying to 
(1) continuously run a thread that gets data and saves it to a file 
(2) have a second thread, or incorporate queue, that will stop the program once a user enters a flag (i.e. "stop"). It doesn't interrupt the data gathering/saving thread.

I need help with multithreading. I am trying to run two threads, one that handles data and the second checks for a flag to stop the program.

I learned by trial and error that I can't interrupt a while loop without my computer exploding. Additionally, I have abandoned my GUI code because it made my code too complicated with the mulithreading.

What I want to do is run a thread that gathers data from an Arduino, saves it to a file, and repeats this. The second thread will scan for a **flag** -- which can be a raw_input? I can't think of anything else that a user can do to stop the data acquisition program.

I greatly appreciate any help on this. Here is my code (much of it is pseudocode, as you can see):

```
#threading
import thread
import time

global flag

def monitorData():
    print "running!"
    time.sleep(5)

def stopdata(flag ):

    flag = raw_input("enter stop: ")

    if flag == "stop":
        monitorData.join()

flag = "start"

thread.start_new_thread( monitorData,())
thread.start_new_thread( stopdata,(flag,))
```

The error I am getting is this when I try entering "stop" in the IDLE.

*Unhandled exception in thread started by 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\otangu~1\appdata\local\temp\IDLE_rtmp_h_frd5", line 16, in stopdata
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'join'*

Once again I really appreciate any help, I have taught myself Python so far and this is the first huge wall that I've hit.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like this:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

# "volatile" global shared by threads
active = True

def get_data():
    while active:
        print "working!"
        sleep(3)

def wait_on_user():
    global active
    raw_input("press enter to stop")
    active = False        

th1 = Thread(target=get_data)
th1.start()
th2 = Thread(target=wait_on_user)
th2.start()

th1.join()
th2.join()
```

You made a few obvious and a few less obvious mistakes in your code. First, join is called on a thread object, not a function. Similarly, join doesn't kill a thread, it waits for the thread to finish. A thread finishes when it has no more code to execute. If you want a thread to run until some flag is set, you normally include a loop in your thread that checks the flag every second or so (depending on how precise you need the timing to be).

Also, the threading module is preferred over the lower lever thread module. The latter has been removed in python3.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a silly mistake I made - I should know that `join(), get()`, etc are called on thread objects not functions. 

So with the code you've provided, I would have to physically hit enter or anything besides "stop" for `th1` to continue running, correct? Ideally I would like the `th1` to repeat until the user enters a flag to stop it.

Thanks again for your time and patience

Comment: @Liv nope, th1 will keep running all on it's own. It'll only stop when you enter "stop". Try out the code, you should see "working" printed every 3 sec if you do nothing.

Comment: @Liv I've made a change to my answer to make it more clear. You don't need a `while` loop in `wait_on_user`, it was just there as an example. `th1` doesn't ever stop to wait on `th2` it keeps looping, it only checks to see if `active` has changed (once per loop). This check takes almost no time and doesn't block the thread.

Answer (score 1):

The error you see is a result of calling join on the function. You need to call `join` on the `thread` object. You don't capture a reference to the thread so you have no way to call `join` anyway. You should `join` like so.

```
th1 = thread.start_new_thread( monitorData,())

# later
th1.join()
```

As for a solution, you can use a `Queue` to communicate between threads. The queue is used to send a quit message to the worker thread and if the worker does not pick anything up off the queue for a second it runs the code that gathers data from the arduino.

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue, Empty


def worker(q):
    while True:

        try:
            item = q.get(block=True, timeout=1)

            q.task_done()
            if item == "quit":
                print("got quit msg in thread")
                break

        except Empty:
            print("empty, do some arduino stuff")


def input_process(q):
    while True:
        x = raw_input("")

        if x == 'q':
            print("will quit")
            q.put("quit")
            break

q = Queue()
t = Thread(target=worker, args=(q,))
t.start()

t2 = Thread(target=input_process, args=(q,))
t2.start()

# waits for the `task_done` function to be called
q.join()

t2.join()
t.join()
```

It's possibly a bit more code than you hoped for and having to detect the queue is empty with an exception is a little ugly, but this doesn't rely on any global variables and will always exit promptly. That wont be the case with `sleep` based solutions, which need to wait for any current calls to `sleep` to finish before resuming execution.

As noted by someone else, you should really be using `threading` rather than the older `thread` module and also I would recommend you learn with python 3 and not python 2.

Comment: I definitely will move over to Python3 once I am done with this project. I was just hoping for some clarification which you have provided - thank you! My issue is trying to have the `worker()` function continuously run until the user enters the flag. I should have been more clear in my original question, ideally I don't want the user to have to hit enter to run the arduino code every time. Once again thank you for your help! I really appreciate your patience

Comment: You don't need to keep pressing a key to have it continue to probe the arduino. Try running it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The thread function has to finish. You can't join it from the outside.

Comment: `.join` is for thread objects, not functions! I get it now. Thank you!:)

Comment: yes but the thread objects from different module. The thread module can't join threads.